# Python get all camera Indexes and Name

Tags: python, opencv

I need to get all available the camera port eg cv2.videoCapture(0).
Running a loop and finding whether the index is valid or not is too slow.

```
for i in range(100): 
    cap = VideoCapture(i)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
         camera_index.append(i)
```

I found an other solution using pygrabber but it only works on windows and also encounters issues if both cameras have same name.
Looking for something that work on linux and windows and is not time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following answer for Linux:

> I believe that under Linux the valid indices for video inputs are the
> numbers of the videoN devices in the /dev directory. Hence the
> following will give a list of valid indices:

```
import os
devs = os.listdir('/dev')
vid_indices = [int(dev[-1]) for dev in devs 
               if dev.startswith('video')]
vid_indices = sorted(vid_indices)
vid_indices
```

[Link](https://discuss.dizzycoding.com/listing-available-devices-in-python-opencv/)